# How to check the value of the node when performing a Firebase transaction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running a Firebase transaction at a specific location but before updating it, I need to make sure that it is not greater than a specific number. How do I do this in Node.JS? My present code isn't working.

My attempted code:

```
var reward_count_red_ref = admin
  .database()
  .ref("Rewards/" + Artcall_ID + "/" + reward_id + "/rewards_left");

reward_count_red_ref
  .transaction(current => {
    const increment = -1 * ticket_count;
    console.log("Going to check if tickets are available");

    if (ticket_count > current) {
      console.log("Tickets not available. The current value is:", current);
    } else {
      return (current || 0) + increment;
      console.log("They are available. The current value is:  ", current);
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Tickets updated.");
    admin
      .database()
      .ref(
        "/Reserve_Project_Request/" + Artcall_ID + "/" + User_ID + "/Response"
      )
      .set("success");
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you wrote is missing a few ingredients to help you debug the problem and make it function correctly.

A transaction returns an object with two arguments: `{ committed, snapshot }`. It is essential that you check the `committed` boolean to see if the transaction actually changed something. In your case, if `committed` is `false` you want to notify the user that the tickets were not available.

Also note that `current` might be `null` (and will be on most of the first runs of the transaction). You might want to handle that case differently and check for `snapshot.exists()`.

Another thing that is missing is the `catch` clause. It could very well be that your transaction failed. If it does, you might be missing it. It's also a good plan to return `.set(...)` call to make sure you catch that result as well.

Another thing that might go wrong is that some other code is using `set` or `update` to modify the data at that location. If that is happening the transaction will be cancelled.

As for the code in the transaction itself, it looks quite ok. The `current || 0` does not make much sense though. If current is `null` and `ticket_count` is a positive number (which I think you have a guard for in another place) it will never reach this branch.

I would personally change `(current || 0) + increment` into `current - ticket_count` to make it more readable, but that's just taste.

---

**Update**

You can access `committed` and `snapshot` like this:

`ref.transaction(...).then(({ committed, snapshot }) => ...)`

If you want failed transactions to retry you could use a function like this:

```
async function withRetries(ref, transaction, attempts = 0) {
  try {
    const result = await ref.transaction(transaction, undefined, false)
    return result
  } catch (e) {
    if (attempts < MAX_TRANSACTION_ATTEMPTS) return withRetries(ref, transaction, attempts + 1)
    throw new Error(`transaction failed ${MAX_TRANSACTION_ATTEMPTS} times, error: ${e.message}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail as to where these arguments would come in? I'm checking the docs and I can't find it!

Comment: Also, if the transaction is cancelled, how do I rereun that method?

Comment: @ArjunRam I updated my answer. As for the documentation, look at the bottom (where it states **returns**) of the transaction documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#transaction

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just add conditions to `current`:

```
  if (current > value) {
    return { name: { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace' } };
  } else {
    return; // Abort the transaction.
  }
```

Comment: Hey so I tried this. The JSON object gets updated but if I write the command return current - ticket_count, it doesn't work! Why's that?